# Draw an arch from one point to another

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I have 2 point given in a vertical line, (x0,y0) and (x0,y1) and I want to connect these two points with an arch (to look like a loop - or like the half of a circumference-) which beggins at (x0,y0) and ends at (x0,y1).

If the connection could look like an arrow which points from the beggining to the end that would be perfect.

All of this using Graphics or whatever.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'arc', and there are methods so named to draw them.

Answer (score 3):

The code below produces this screenshot, it will draw half a circle between two points + adds an arrow in the end:

[image: screemshot]

Code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.add(new JComponent() {
    Point p1, p2; boolean first;
    {
        p1 = p2 = new Point();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (first) p1 = e.getPoint(); else p2 = e.getPoint();
                first = !first;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(p1.x-1, p1.y-1, 3, 3); g.drawString("p1", p1.x, p1.y);   
        g.fillRect(p2.x-1, p2.y-1, 3, 3); g.drawString("p2", p2.x, p2.y);

        double angle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
        int diameter = (int) Math.round(p1.distance(p2));

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(p1.x, p1.y);
        g2d.rotate(angle);
        g2d.drawArc(0, -diameter/2, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);
        g2d.fill(new Polygon(new int[] {0,10,-10}, new int[] {0,-10,-10}, 3));
    }
});
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

- [Overview of the Java 2D API Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html) contains tutorials about [Geometric Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/primitives.html)
- here you can find out an answer to your question(s), [bunch examples here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm)
- notice for painting to `AWT Component` is there method `paint()`, for `Swing JComponent` is there method `paintComponent()`
- for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issues with your question :

> I have 2 point given in a vertical line, (x0,y0) and (x0,y1) and I want to connect these two points with an arch (to look like a loop - or like the half of a circumference-) which beggins at (x0,y0) and ends at (x0,y1).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an arc painting example:

```
public class ArcExample extends JComponent
{
    protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent ( g );

        Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        g2d.setColor ( Color.RED );
        g2d.drawArc ( 0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight (), 90, -180 );
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
    {
        return new Dimension ( 200, 200 );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.add ( new ArcExample () );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: And how I could connect the two points?? with a loop maybe? But would you know how to handle it? Thanks

Comment: You can see the two-points conection in example @dacwe added (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10833380/909085). Or if its not what you are looking for - add some explanation image...